# Gitlab DID cache not working

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I’ve an Omnibus installation of Gitlab in my local server, and on another server a gitlab-runner that performs the CI tasks.

In my pipeline I’ve a Job that check the code quality using Docker In Docker with codeclimate.

The problem is that it is very slow (20 minutes) because every time it download and extract the docker images of codeclimate.

```
docker pull codeclimate/codeclimate
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from codeclimate/codeclimate 
2f3f3e5e133b: Pulling fs layer
2654c654a6e7: Pulling fs layer
412e64056adf: Pulling fs layer
a3ed95caeb02: Pulling fs layer
b79986a12326: Pulling fs layer
1bbb14422caf: Pulling fs layer
46bd7e5026ba: Pulling fs layer
7df61bb88827: Pulling fs layer
0381f4ee19b5: Pulling fs layer
7df87a0871f8: Pulling fs layer
4d99acb499d7: Pulling fs layer
ee6a20c6ea98: Pulling fs layer
cb945e8bccc7: Pulling fs layer
a789fd50eff6: Pulling fs layer
1bbb14422caf: Waiting
46bd7e5026ba: Waiting
7df61bb88827: Waiting
a3ed95caeb02: Waiting
b79986a12326: Waiting
7df87a0871f8: Waiting
4d99acb499d7: Waiting
cb945e8bccc7: Waiting
a789fd50eff6: Waiting
ee6a20c6ea98: Waiting
412e64056adf: Download complete
```

I tried to configure the gitlab-ci cache but nothing changed.

```
cache:
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
    untracked: true

stage: reports
  image: docker:latest
  before_script: []
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script: 
    - docker info
    - docker pull codeclimate/codeclimate
    - mkdir -pv build/reports/codequality
    - cp .codeclimate.yml src
    - docker run --env CODECLIMATE_DEBUG=1 --env CODECLIMATE_CODE="$PWD/src" --volume "$PWD/src":/code --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --volume /tmp/cc:/tmp/cc codeclimate/codeclimate validate-config
    - docker run --env CODECLIMATE_DEBUG=1 --env CODECLIMATE_CODE="$PWD/src" --volume "$PWD/src":/code --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --volume /tmp/cc:/tmp/cc codeclimate/codeclimate analyze -f html > build/reports/codequality/codequality.html
    - docker run --env CODECLIMATE_DEBUG=1 --env CODECLIMATE_CODE="$PWD/src" --volume "$PWD/src":/code --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --volume /tmp/cc:/tmp/cc codeclimate/codeclimate analyze -f json > build/reports/codequality/raw_codequality.json
    - cat build/reports/codequality/raw_codequality.json
    - cat build/reports/codequality/raw_codequality.json | docker run -i stedolan/jq -c 'map({check_name,fingerprint,location})' > build/reports/codequality/codequality.json
    - rm src/.codeclimate.yml
```

This is my config.toml

```
[[runners]]
  name = "DockerBuilder"
  url = "http://gitlab.mycompany.com"
  token = "mytoken"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/etc/default/docker:/etc/default/docker", "/etc/docker/daemon.json:/etc/docker/daemon.json"]
    extra_hosts = ["localhost:172.X.X.X"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

I've followed this guide: [Analyze project code quality with Code Climate CLI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/code_climate.html)

Comment: I am experiencing similar issues, with my config being almost 100% identical to that of the guide. I did find this issue on GitLab regarding the docker-in-docker service not caching images. It is still open. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/17861

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: not yet Unfortunately